# How to make my function only run on firefox?

Tags: jquery

How can test the browser and run my function only for firefox?

```
function myFunc(){
console.log('this should be run only on firefox browser');
}
```

---

I came to know jquery.browser is deprecated and says use support instead so I tried $.support.mozilla not work. So how can I do it with support method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[navigator agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent)**:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
     function myFunc(){
         console.log('this should be run only on firefox browser');
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check with this

```
$.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version > '2' (deprecated)
```

So use

```
$.browser.version < '1.9'
```

Note

Because $.browser uses navigator.userAgent to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible. Instead of relying on $.browser it's better to use libraries like Modernizr.

Will not work in jQuery 1.9 or later unless the jQuery Migrate plugin is included.

Answer (score 0):

If i would have to build something like this, i would use this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
    alert("Jups, is FireFox");
} else { 
    alert("Nope, not FireFox");   
}
```

Here you go, i set up a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/A47tb/1/